# TabView with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

In my app initially I created one class "abc.java" which extends Activity and do some functionality..

But now I have decided to implement TabView and abc.java should be first tab in tabview..

My problem is my abc.java class extends activity and now when I change it to fragments , it gives me errors.

If I implement TabActivity , which is deprecated now, it will work fine, but now if I want to use fragment what changes I have to do?

I know I have to make some changes in abc.java but I have no clue how to do that..I am new to android and trying hard to get this done..Any help would be great!!

here is my code for class "abc.java"

```
public class CountAndMarkPage extends Activity
{
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.count_mark);

        //lots of code here
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to extend Fragment and override onCreateView using the same layout resource.  Have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#UI) info from docs.

Quick example:

```
public class CountAndMarkPage extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Inflate your layout
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.count_mark, container, false);

        // Any additional initialization

        return myView;
    }
}
```

---

To access widgets within this layout, you'll need to use findViewById on the inflated root view like so

```
public class CountAndMarkPage extends Fragment {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // Inflate your layout
        ViewGroup myView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.count_mark, container, false);

        // Any additional initialization
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.my_view);
        // And so on
        return myView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used same approach by looking at other examples , but it gives me error cause actually OnCreate of my abc.java I am using other widgets too..and it gives me error on findViewById method    for example: mLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl1);
        blue_tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blueTV);

Comment: You need to use the root view to access its children, as you're no longer setting the content view of the activity within abc.java.

Comment: Yess .. you are right..even if  I do so ..I am getting same error..what could be wrong here??

Comment: I am sorry..I overlooked your code..It is working...but I have some other error on this method getApplicationContext() and getWindowManager()..I am using it in one of my function..

Comment: Those methods require an Activity.  Within the fragment, try getActivity.getApplicationContext() and getActivity.getWindowManager().

Comment: getActivity() rather -> getActivity().getApplicationContext() and getActivity().getWindowManager()

Comment: Thanks a lotttttt..you really saved my day..I had been trying to find the solution whole day..Thanks a lot!!